# Graphics glitch with Pixi.js

Tags: graphics, pixi.js

I'm trying to generate a pixelated circle with pixi.js and am having some issues.

With this code:

```
for (var x = 0; x <= r; x+=10)
    {
        var drawY = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(r,2) - Math.pow(x,2)).roundTo(10);
        for (var y = 0; y <= drawY; y += 10)
        {
            graphics.drawRect(x , y, 10, 10);
            graphics.drawRect(y , x, 10, 10);
            graphics.drawRect(-x , y, 10, 10);
            graphics.drawRect(-y , x, 10, 10);
            graphics.drawRect(x , -y, 10, 10);
            graphics.drawRect(y , -x, 10, 10);
            // graphics.drawRect(-x, -y, 10, 10);
            // graphics.drawRect(-y, -x, 10, 10);
        }

    }
```

I get this:

[image]

If I uncomment those last two lines to give me the last quadrant, I get this:

[image]

If I comment everything except for those last two lines, I get this:

[image]

I thought maybe it had something to do with the size of the texture or maybe since it is drawing in negative coordinates, but neither of those make sense looking at the results from the other quadrants.

**Edit**

Messed around with my code and came up with a much more efficient way of drawing the circle, but now the problem seems even more strange.

```
graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
```

gives:

[image]

while

```
graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
graphics.drawRect(0,-200,10,10);
```

gives the exact same thing (still only the one square), but

```
graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
graphics.drawRect(0,200,10,10);
```

gives:

[image]

and

```
graphics.drawRect(0,0,10,10);
graphics.drawRect(-200,-200,10,10);
```

gives:

[image]

**Update again**

So if I draw a grid of squares around the entire thing, the circle draws perfectly.

[image]